# Twosided lollipop chart - adding labels for difference (either absolute or in percent?)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following twosided lollipop chart:

[image]

**I would like to:**

- add labels for the delta between downstream/upstream, can either be in % or absolute
- because the graph will most likely be overcrowded, I would want to only add them to the largest differences

I first thought about annotate(...) but it requires an X argument, which in my case is a non-numeric axis

**Reproducible Example:**

```
example = read.table(text = "    Sector Upstream Downstream
1 Agriculture  2.84   9.33
2 Mining      13.77   12.96
3 Foodproducts 3.04   29.12
4 Textiles      0.72 2.57
5 Wood          3.61   2.55
6 Paper  17.01 29.65", header = TRUE)
```

And the respective graph:

```
ggplot(example) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=Sector, xend=Sector, y=Upstream, yend=Downstream), color="black") +
  geom_point( aes(x=Sector, y=Upstream, color=("Upstream")), size=2 ) +
  geom_point( aes(x=Sector, y=Downstream, color=("Downstream")), size=2 ) +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "deepskyblue4"), name   = "Loss-Type")+
  ylab("Losses")
```

[image]
  
Is there a "straight-forward" way in accomplishing this? Most ressources I found online specify the labels for one sided lollipop graphs.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could first calculate the absolute difference between Upstream and Downstream with `abs`. After you could calculate the average between Upstream and Downstream with `rowMeans` to get the x position of the label to your graph. To slightly adjust the labels you could use `nudge_x` with useful on discrete scales like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
example = example %>%
  mutate(abs_diff = abs(Upstream - Downstream)) %>%
  mutate(mean_pos = rowMeans(.[,2:3])) 

ggplot(example) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=Sector, xend=Sector, y=Upstream, yend=Downstream), color="black") +
  geom_point( aes(x=Sector, y=Upstream, color=("Upstream")), size=2 ) +
  geom_point( aes(x=Sector, y=Downstream, color=("Downstream")), size=2 ) +
  geom_text( aes(x = Sector, y = mean_pos, label = round(abs_diff, 2)), nudge_x = 0.2) +
  coord_flip()+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "deepskyblue4"), name   = "Loss-Type")+
  ylab("Losses")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the difference between Upstream and Downstream and then find the maximum value of Upstream and Downstream for the location of the label.  You could then set some delta values to NA if they are below a pre-determined threshold (to prevent overcrowding, I used 5 here).  Then, you could use `geom_text()` to add the labels.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
example = read.table(text = "    Sector Upstream Downstream
1 Agriculture  2.84   9.33
2 Mining      13.77   12.96
3 Foodproducts 3.04   29.12
4 Textiles      0.72 2.57
5 Wood          3.61   2.55
6 Paper  17.01 29.65", header = TRUE)

example <- example %>% 
  mutate(delta = round(Downstream - Upstream, 1), 
         delta = ifelse(abs(delta) > 5, delta, NA), 
         labloc = apply(cbind(Downstream, Upstream), 1, max))

ggplot(example) +
  geom_segment( aes(x=Sector, xend=Sector, y=Upstream, yend=Downstream), color="black") +
  geom_point( aes(x=Sector, y=Upstream, color=("Upstream")), size=2 ) +
  geom_point( aes(x=Sector, y=Downstream, color=("Downstream")), size=2 ) +
  geom_text(aes(x=Sector, y=labloc, label=delta), nudge_y=1, hjust=0) + 
  ylim(0, 35) + 
  coord_flip()+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "deepskyblue4"), name   = "Loss-Type")+
  ylab("Losses")
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (`geom_text()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>